# iOS - Twitter not working on iOS 5 after upgrading project to iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter, ios6

After I upgraded my project to Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6, none of the twitter framework functionality works when running on the iOS 5.1 simulator. Everything is fine on iOS 6, but when I run on 5.1, I get an error of

```
twitterd session interrupted, restarting
```

And then the app freezes. I can switch to the iOS 6 simulator and then it works perfectly.

I'm just using the Twitter framework, not the new social framework. Did Apple change something? This error happens whenever I try to access an account from ACAccountStore or pull up a tweet sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've noticed a number of issues that seem to only effect the iOS 5.1 simulator. Have you tried on the iOS 5.0 simulator or (better) on an iOS 5.1 device?

Comment: All seems to be good on iOS 5.0 simulator. On 5.1, I can't even get into the Twitter part of Settings.app, so something is obviously broken there. I'll give it a try on a 5.1 device as well. Thank you!

Comment: I've seen similar issues since upgrading. Everything appears to work fine on iOS 5.x devices though.

Comment: add social, adsupport, account framework and make it optional it will work for ios 6.0 and xcode 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Twitter frame work is deprecated in ios 6 you have to switch to Social Framework which is common to facebook, twitter and SinaWeibo..